# Opening an ASP.NET page from the parent page in a separate window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net pages. One is `parent.aspx` and the other is `child.aspx`.

The `parent.aspx` contains a button.

Whenever I click that button on `parent.aspx`, I want the `child.aspx` to appear in another window of my desired size over the parent window just like popup but not popup.

I have used `window.Open()` script function. But stuck about what c# code should I write on the back end.

What can I do in such situation?

Comment: Are you looking for `button.OnClientClick = "<script>window.Open(url);return false;</script>";`

Comment: @Varun,Mark as Answer if found useful

Answer (score 1):

Pass Parameter `_blank` in window something like following:-

```
function popWin()
{
  window.open (url, 'mynewwin', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=600,height=520,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');
}
```

### In Code Behind

```
void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
 Button1.Attributes.Add( "onclick", "popWin();return false;" ); 
}
```

Comment: The code given by you will be written in the asp.net page.But what about the backend c# code?

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this:

```
<script>window.open(url, 'nameofurl', 'width=420,height=500 ,scrollbars=yes');return false; </script>
```

Here you will set the width and height of new window...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Or this

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#video-player